# Change value of a input (write into the input) when a option is selected from a select

Tags: jquery, html

**Hi,**

I got the following input

```
<input type="text" class="input-text" value="South Yorkshire" placeholder=" county" name="calc_shipping_state" id="calc_shipping_state">
```

And I need to change it for a select dropdown with few options. The problem is that input makes a validation with a database and I do not have access to the HTML. So I'm hiding the input and adding a select option using jQuery to write into the input the option selected. I'm not sure how can I write into the hiding input the option selected on the select.

Using `.change()` or `.val()` ?

This is the code to add the select:

```
  $('#calc_shipping_state_field').after("<p class='form-row form-row-wide' id='calc_shipping_state_field' id=''> <select name='' id='county_selected' class='' rel=''> <option value=''>Select a county…</option>  <option value='BE'>Bedfordshire</option> <option selected='selected' value='BER'>Berkshire</option> <option value='BRI'>Bristol</option> <option value='BUCK'>Buckinghamshire</option> <option value='CA'>Cambridgeshire</option> <option value='CHES'>Cheshire</option> <option value='LN'>City of London</option> </select></p>");
```

I have added `selected='selected'` on the 'Berkshire' option to make by default

```
<option selected='selected' value='BER'>Berkshire</option>
```

And this is the code I have tried using .change() but doesn't work.

```
$( "#county_selected" ).change(function() {
    var county = $("select :selected").county(function () {
    var txt = $(this).text();
    }).get();
    //add it to div
    $('input.input-text').val('county');
  });
```

I hope someone can help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find()` to get the selected option, then call `.text()` on it. In the change function, `this` refers to the select, so there's no need to reselect it.

```
$( "#county_selected" ).change(function() {
    $('input.input-text').val($(this).find('option:selected').text());
});
```

The above code must run after the select is added. If you prefer you can delegate to a parent or the document and it doesn't have to run after the select is added:

```
$(document).on('change', '#county_selected', function(){
    $('input.input-text').val($(this).find('option:selected').text());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can do this by using [JQuery replaceWith Method](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=replaceWith):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  /*
  * Make your new HTML ELEMENT
  */
  var newHTMLelment  = "<select name='calc_shipping_state'>";
      newHTMLelment += "<option value='01'>01</option>";
      newHTMLelment += "<option value='02'>02</option>";
      newHTMLelment += "</select>";
  /*
  * Replace current HTML element with new one
  */
  $( "#calc_shipping_state" ).replaceWith( newHTMLelment );

});
```

Comment: Thanks @hmd  your code works as well but I think the other one is more clean.

Comment: Well, you can at least Vote up then :) @andresgl

Comment: Sure! Thanks a lot again!